# Double pointer to char[]

Tags: c, pointers, casting

Alright, so I have the following code:

```
char** args = (char**)malloc(10*sizeof(char*));
memset(args, 0, sizeof(char*)*10);

char* curToken = strtok(string, ";");

for (int z = 0; curToken != NULL; z++) {
    args[z] = strdup(curToken);
    curToken = strtok(NULL, ";")
}
```

I want every `arg[z]` casted into an array of chars -- char string[100] -- and then processed in the algorithms I have following. Every `arg[z]` needs to be casted to the variable string at some point. I am confused by pointers, but I am slowly getting better at them.

EDIT:

```
char string[100] = "ls ; date ; ls";
```

`arg[0]` will be ls, `arg[1]` will be date, and `arg[2]` will be ls after the above code.

I want to put each argument back into char string[100] and process it through algorithms.

Comment: (Aside) `memset` is not reliable with pointers; there's no guarantee that the null pointer is all zeroes. (On common hardware it is, but a loop over `args` to set each element to `NULL` is more portable and more explicit.)

Comment: What if there are more than `10` tokens? `args` is only good enough for `10`. The casts to `malloc` are not required. Also, what is your actual question?

Comment: Not really sure what the question is, the code looks fine except there is no control over indexing `args`.

Comment: consider calloc() if you want to clear your malloc'd memory.  Also, not really sure what you are asking here...

Comment: Don't cast the return value of malloc!

Comment: I think I see what you're trying to do, but it will be a little more in depth than what you're after.  Correct me if I'm wrong, but you are trying to concatenate all of the strings stored in `arg` into a single string.  C natively provides no way to do this.  Casting the pointer will not behave as you expect, because once everything is said and done, it contains pointers and not characters.  Can you update with an example, including an input string and your expected output?  I'm not quite sure how you want it.

Comment: Update above. Hopefully it clears some things up! There will be no more than 10 tokens.

Comment: "I want to put each argument back into char string[100]" - what will the string contain if you do it? Something like `ls  date  ls`? Is this what you want?

Comment: I figured out an implementation. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

one easiest way is to keep a backup of the original string in some temporary variable.

```
char string[100] = "ls ; date ; ls"; 
char temp_str[100] = {0};
strcpy (temp_str, string);
```

Another way is to do it by `strcat`. `z` has the number of agruments.

```
memset(string, '\0', 100);
for (i = 0; i < z; i++)
{
    strcat(string, args[i]);
    if (i != (z - 1))
    {
        //if it is last string dont append semicolon
        strcat(string, ";");
    }
}
```

Note : Take care of the boundary condition check

Answer (score 0):

If you want the parts of string copied into a fixed length string[100] then you need to malloc 100 chars for each args[] inside the loop and strncpy() the result of strtok into it.  strdup will only allocate enough memory for the actual length of the supplied string (plus \0)

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
char** args = (char**)malloc(10*sizeof(char*));
memset(args, 0, sizeof(char*)*10);
```

is broken code. First, you shouldn't cast `malloc()`'s return value. Second, `args` is a pointer to ten pointers to `char`. You can't set them to `NULL` using `memset()`, there's no guarantee that "all bytes zero" is the same as `NULL`. You need to use a loop.